# PHP. Does inline(single line) html code rendering faster?

Tags: html, css

My frontend PHP co-worker wonders me again and again. I gonna shoot him soon)))

The html code of page is single line

```
<html><title></title><div></div></html>
```

Allways thought that must be:

```
 <html>
    <title></title>
     <body>
    <div> 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page that contains 100 products is single line. It's hardly understand something.

Does browser's renders inline html code faster?

Comment: It might be a little faster, because the file is smaller, but I doubt it will impact the speed alot. Outputting it with gzip would probably help more than this. Also, writing it in a single line decreases readability alot. It's OK if you don't need to edit the file anymore, but if you still have to edit you might want to have all your indents for the sake of readability.

Comment: If you *write* it like that by hand, you're an idiot. If you automatically strip whitespace and send it like that to the browser... meh, why not?

Comment: I'm guessing this will only contribute to; 1. Decreased readability, 2. Slower output from PHP (PHP have to replace each linebreak), 3. No noticeable change in loading time or render time, 4. Increased possibility for debugging problems.

Comment: @Daniel *"PHP have to replace each linebreak"*... What do you mean?

Comment: @deceze - Im guessing that he is not coding the output templates on a single line. Thus some sort of `str_replace("\n","",$buffer)` is required.

Comment: @Daniel Going on that assumption... okay. That's not entirely clear though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This clearly is wrong optimization. The performance difference is never going to be noticed. It would be in the order of milliseconds or less.

However your making the code a lot harder to maintain. Which will probably cost you money in the long run, because it takes longer to understand what's going on.

Simply put, the **potential** performance gains never outweigh the extra cost of maintaining that code.